# Searching for string in file and returning that specific line

Tags: java, file, search, text, line

I am working on student registration system. I have a text file with studentname, studentnumber and the student's grade stored in every line such as:

```
 name1,1234,7
 name2,2345,8
 name3,3456,3
 name4,4567,10
 name5,5678,6
```

How can I search a name and then return the whole sentence? It does not get any matches when looking for the name.

my current code look like this:

```
public static void retrieveUserInfo()
{
    System.out.println("Please enter username"); //Enter the username you want to look for
    String inputUsername = userInput.nextLine();


    final Scanner scanner = new Scanner("file.txt");
    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
       if(lineFromFile.contains(inputUsername)) { 
           // a match!
           System.out.println("I found " +inputUsername+ " in file " ); // this should return the whole line, so the name, student number and grade
           break;
       }
       else System.out.println("Nothing here");
    }
```

Comment: Language = Java? If so, include in tag. Also it seems that `lineFromFile` already contains your whole line, so just print that....

Comment: Added the tag and printed lineFromFile but it still does not find matches. Could that have something to do with the seperation by the comma in the textfile?

Comment: If you add `System.out.println(lineFromFile);` Right after your `if` statement, what output do you get?

Comment: while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
     final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
     if(lineFromFile.contains(inputUsername)) { 
         // a match!
         System.out.println(lineFromFile );
         break;
     }
     else System.out.println("Nothing here");


Returns Nothing here

Comment: Just ''nothing here''

Comment: Are you aware that such greping is case sensitive? You may need to use `lineFromFile.toLowerCase().contains(inputUserName.trim().toLowerCase())`

Comment: I was just about to say if you are sure you even go into your if statement, try using the debugger and step through everything and see what happens. And +1 @MaciejDobrowolski

Comment: @MaciejDobrowolski Should I add that line in the condition of the if-statement? Because I tried to do so but no luck so far.

Comment: Maybe you should go back to something more simple than this, if this is too hard for you. Try reading a book about Java syntax and the internet is your friend. Look up what all the built in library functions do and return.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with `Scanner(String)` constructor as it:

> public Scanner(java.lang.String source)
>
> Constructs a new Scanner that produces values scanned from the
>   specified string.
>
> Parameters: source - A string to scan

it does not know anything about files, just about strings. So, the only line that this `Scanner` instance can give you (via `nextLine()` call) is `file.txt`.

Simple test would be:

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner("any test string");
assertEquals("any test string", scanner.nextLine());
```

You should use other constructor of `Scanner` class such as:

```
Scanner(InputStream)
Scanner(File)
Scanner(Path)
```

Answer (score 0):

You already have the variable that holds the whole line. Just print it like this:

```
while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
       final String lineFromFile = scanner.nextLine();
       if(lineFromFile.contains(inputUsername)) { 
           // a match!
           System.out.println("I found " +lineFromFile+ " in file " ); 
           break;
       }
       else System.out.println("Nothing here");
    }
```